# Issue with ActionListener with JButton

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on a game for my first Java class. I had to create two different buttons with two different action listeners. The TreasureButton extends from the EmptyButton and each have a different listener.

The issue that I am having is that when I try to set the test in the empty button listener, it overrides the TreasureButton Listener.
For example, the treasure button text is set to "$". If I set the empty button text to "X" then all buttons appear as "X" even if it is a treasure.
I also had to create a last move label and text field. When I run the method under the empty button listener to execute the last move as a "bust", it then only says "bust" even when I uncover a treasure.
I tried @Override in my TreasureButtonListener class but it didn't change anything.
Any guidance on this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class EmptyButton extends JButton
{
    //has-a TreasureGame
    private TreasureGame game;
    
    //has-a TreasureGameView
    private TreasureGameView gameView;
    
    public EmptyButton(TreasureGame game, TreasureGameView gameView)
    {
        super();
        setText("X");
        this.game = game;
        this.gameView = gameView;
        
        addActionListener(new EmptyButtonListener(this, game, gameView));
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class TreasureButton extends EmptyButton
{
   
   public TreasureButton(TreasureGame game, TreasureGameView gameView)
   {
       super(game, gameView);
       
       //setText("$"); 
       addActionListener(new TreasureButtonListener(this, game, gameView));
   }
   
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class EmptyButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    private EmptyButton button;
    //has-a TreasureGame
    private TreasureGame  game;
    //has-a TreasureGameView
    private TreasureGameView gameView;
    
    public EmptyButtonListener(EmptyButton button, TreasureGame game, TreasureGameView gameView)
    {
        this.game = game;
        this.button = button;
        this.gameView = gameView;
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //button.setText("X");
        button.setEnabled(false);
        game.reduceTriesLeft();
        //game.treasureNotFound();
        game.isGameOver();
        
        gameView.updateUI();
    }
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TreasureButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    
    
    // Has-a TreasureButton
    private TreasureButton button;
    private TreasureGame game;
    private TreasureGameView gameView;
    
    public TreasureButtonListener(TreasureButton button, TreasureGame game, TreasureGameView gameView)
    {
        
        this.button = button;
        this.game = game;
        this.gameView = gameView;
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        
        button.setText("$");
        game.reduceNumberStillHidden();
        game.treasureFound();
        
        game.isGameOver();
        gameView.updateUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys I am really new to Java.

Comment: I used removeActionListener(getActionListeners()[0]); and it worked. Thank you.